# Capture error between SQL Server and Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Here I am with a puzzle where I have to capture SQL error and perform other task like

insert/update/delete

The same thing I have done it before in SQL Server stored procedure and success on it. Now here is same thing but situation change. I have done Insert code for multiple table in my project at large basis in Visual Studio 2005 and if I decide to move whole code to store procedure than it will really headache for me to adjust lot of parametrized value between SQL Server and Visual Studio 2005.

Hence I am asking about pull out the way.

The real matter is I have coded of Insert into multiple table around seven to eight tables and first I have to check the matters If such matters is true than abundant the task else insert into table.

**I have checked the matters in SQL Server and Visual Studio 2005 as below:**

```
declare @bb decimal(12,2)
declare @cc decimal(12,2)
select @bb=  sum(coalesce(issued,0)) from compareMFG
select @cc= sum(coalesce(returnn,0)) from compareMFG
if @bb > @cc 
begin
--print 'yah'
raiserror('Sorry',16,10)
end
```

And it works.

I want that if such error occurs than abundant the insert into table task but if there are no error than it will allow to insert the records into multiple table.

**And I want the same task on Visual Studio 2005**

**Is there a way?.**

Comment: Split the check/insert combination into multiple SP if possible

Comment: @Ramhound, It's too large but you can imagine as for insert into one or two table and the point is that how to capture the sql error in c#

Comment: @V4Vendetta, You are right and I have mention in my post that I have tried before in SP and C#-2005 and got success on it but I don't know how to do it in C#-2005 alone.

Comment: @marc_s, I am really struggling that If you not understand my question  than how did you edited it?. Is it possible edit the question without understand?.

Comment: ... what is the meaning of edit. Is does mean to leave as it is or improve it?. and in such case first you have to understand it.

Comment: I just cleaned up your various `VS_2005`, `VS-2005`, `VS2005` abbreviations and so on - to make it look cleaner and consistent - that's all ... just by editing it doesn't mean I **understand** what you ask (yet) ....

Comment: @marc_s, Oh! yes I am sorry marc as i forgot that there no rules to editing the question. any one can editing it without understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above question I have marked   **“Star 1”** for **Experiment and Learn** but unfortunately the important question got minus vote.  I think that the peers who provided
minus vote is not think beside the subject and principal. I know that SP is the Wright solution for the above problem but here I experiment with the above and see I have got success on it which will going to Share with our community.

As per my point of view the **“SQL TRANSACTION”**  is the best choice.  The SqlTransaction Class is control the Transact Sql Which will **commit** and **Rollback.** Here I apply the same With above Problem in VS-2005.

```
string connstr = "Server=.;initial catalog=DataBase;uid=uid;pwd=pwd";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
con.Open();
SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();

try
{

    string err = @"declare @bb decimal(12,2)" +
                " declare @cc decimal(12,2)" +
                " select @bb=  sum(coalesce(issued,0)) from compareMFG where companyID=@companyID and jagadNo=@jagadNo" +
                " select @cc= sum(coalesce(returnn,0)) from compareMFG where companyID=@companyID and jagadNo=@jagadNo" +
                " if @bb = @cc " +
                " begin" +
                " raiserror('Sorry',16,10)" +
                " end";
                SqlCommand errcmd = new SqlCommand(err, con);
                errcmd.Transaction = trans;
                errcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("jagadNo", comboBox1.Text);
                errcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyID", label18.Text);
                errcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 // Here you can do extra task for inserting into table
 //And after that comit it like below:

 trans.Commit();

 }
 //here you can cath the any error including SQL
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exx.Message);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

So If the Boolean value true than the transaction will **RollBack**  And Fired the Exception Whether it is **VS OR SQL** and if Boolean value false than it will automatically allow to insert the statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `raiserror` inside your SP then your client-side call to `ExecuteNonQuery` comes back with an `SqlException` which you can `catch` (in a `try`... `catch` block) - this has a property called [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) which is a collection of [`SqlError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.aspx) objects. `SqlError` has a property called [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.message.aspx) which contains the message you sent via `raiserror` - it has several other properties which might be of interest... check/read the links...

Comment: You are absolutely wright but it's not my solution. I have already said in my question that I have idea about SP and also knew how to  handle it to VS-2005. My research ask about Is there a way in VS-2005 like SP in above condition?.

Comment: Then I really don't understand your question... what do you mean by "VS-2005 like SP" ?